# reference Object Array Name as property

Tags: c#, .net, object

How do I get the property name of an object array to use in a SWITCH / CASE function as follows?  Any other suggestions on how to do this are appreciated.

```
Object[] objEURUSD = ConvertStringtoObjectArray(string val1);

Object[] objAUDUSD = ConvertStringtoObjectArray(string val2);

Object[] objGBPUSD = ConvertStringtoObjectArray(string val3);
```

Example Function Use

```
Object[] mvavgEURUSD = mvavgObject(objEURUSD);


private Object[] mvavgObject(Object[] val)
{

    string sym = val.ToString()  // this does not return the name it returns 'System.Object'

    switch (sym)
    {
        case "objEURUSD":

            // do something
            break;

        case "objAUDUSD":

            // do something
            break;

        case "objGBPUSD":
            // do something
            break;

    }
}
```

I could include the name of the object 'EURUSD' in the Object Array itself, but it's already inlcuded in the name of the object.. I just can't figure out how to reference the name of the object.. either I don't know or I am not conversant with Reflection.

I appreciate your help or suggestions on the matter.

Comment: Your code doesn’t compile and doesn’t make sense. Please post real code, not something that only approximates code. Also, please post the declaration of `ConvertStringtoObjectArray`, otherwise we have no way of guessing what it does.

Comment: Why (and how) would you convert a string to `Object[]` ????

Comment: It was a mistake it should read : Object[] objAUDUSD = ConvertStringtoObjectArray(String[] val2);

Comment: okay, it's a function and there are some mistakes.  I am only trying to learn if there is a way to reference the name property of an object array... That's it.  The reason I am converting the String[] array to Object[] is not that important.. if it was a String[] array the questions still applies.  But the answer is speed an it's a better format for using as a static variable throughout the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get the property name of an object array to use in a SWITCH / CASE function ?

By *not* doing the conversion. You can use a `string` in a switch statement, but not an `object[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't because there is no such "name" for an object. That wouldn't even make sense - many variables can hold a reference to the same object. Which one should be the "name"?

Imagine for a moment that there would be such a function called GetName(). What would the program output in each of these cases?

Case 1:

```
var a = new MyObject();
var b = a;
Console.WriteLine(GetName(b)); // Is it "a" or "b"?
```

Case 2:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetName(new MyObject())); // What is the name now?
```

Case 3:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetName(null)); // I guess you can return null here, but see case 4:
```

Case 4:

```
MyObject a = null;
Console.WriteLine(GetName(a)); // Should this be "a" or null?
```

And so on and so forth.

If you want to give your objects "names", you'll have to do so yourself. Perhaps create a "NamedObject" wrapper class like this:

```
class NamedObject<T>
{
    public readonly T Object;
    public readonly string Name;

    public NamedObject(string name, string value)
    {
        this.Object = value;
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I think that's an interesting way to answer this.  I guess the overall answer is no.. but thanks for the reference that Object's do not have names to reference, unless you add them.'

Answer (score 0):

Without further information, I can only guess what `ConvertStringtoObjectArray` does. My guess is that it looks something up using the string as a key, and then returns an array of some values.

In most cases, I would expect that the original string is no longer contained in the object array. Therefore, obviously, you cannot retrieve it, so you will have to “remember” it, i.e. pass it around.

For example, instead of

```
Object[] objEURUSD = ConvertStringtoObjectArray(myVal);
Object[] mvavgEURUSD = mvavgObject(objEURUSD);

private Object[] mvavgObject(Object[] val)
{
    // ...
```

you could write something like this:

```
Object[] mvavgEURUSD = mvavgObject(myVal);

private Object[] mvavgObject(string val)
{
    Object[] objEURUSD = ConvertStringtoObjectArray(val);

    // The string is in the parameter ‘val’, so we can use it here
    switch (val)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the default behavior of ToString() is to return the class name. This can be overridden in any class as all classes inherit from object. string.ToString() is the behavior you are looking for so you probably need to first cast the object back to string (the array part is tricky though since I don't know what the ConvertStringtoObjectArray method does), but you need to do a cast to access what you are looking for.

I assume that the object[] is a char[]? if so the cast should be as easy as casting the object to a char[] and then to the string.

Comment: The object should have been an Array of Strings.. it was mistakenly written.

Comment: Then cast each member of the Array back to a string in your method and you are finished.

Answer (score 0):

if the variable declaration of "objEURUSD" is in your current scope, you could compare your parameter to that variable to see if both are referencing the same object ... this won't lookup some sort of name, but maybe it's what you want...

```
Object[] objEURUSD; //initialized somewhere else


private Object[] mvavgObject(Object[] val)
{
   if(val==objEURUSD)
   {
      //it's the array referenced by objEURUSD ...
   }
}
```

as an alternative, you could use a `Dictionary<string,Object[]>` or `Dictionary<Object[],string>` to store your arrays, so you can lookup the array for a given name or vice versa